# What mean with $this->request->action in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm currently maintain code that has written by other programmer. The application build on CakePHP.

On the application, inside the controller I found `$this->request->action = 'string_value'` which is I don't understand what mean of this comment. I try to search on CakePHP documentation and API, but I get nothing. Also do not found any suitable reference on google.

Can someone explain about this comment?

Answer (score 2):

Basically $this->request is using for accessing request parameters. Please check this [cakephp](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html) article. may be it is setting a request parameter like $_POST["action"]="abcd"; Please check.

Comment: I see that $this->request is instance of CakeRequest. However, I don't get `action` property for this class. see http://api20.cakephp.org/class/cake-request

Comment: Yes. Thats correct. But is there any chance for extending that component(RequestHandler) ? Just look into the code for that.